# SQL - Using Logical Operators (where to put parenthesis)

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, logical-operators

My query is supposed to Count the number of times specific customers were added to the table within the last month. If only use:

```
WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Then I get all 'CustomerID' and 'TimesReturned' within that last month, and this seems valid, but when I search for the specific entries using 'AND' & 'OR' - I Get the result shown below, however this result is no longer counting entries within the last month.

In fact, when I include more or less specific customers in the search, the 'TimesReturned' value changes. So if i search for 'cust1-4' and then 'cust1-2' - the TimesReturned count for 1 and 2 changes.

MyQuery:

```
SELECT TOP 20 Return_Table.Customer_ID, COUNT(*) AS TimesReturned
FROM Return_Table         
WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust1' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust2' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust3' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust4'
GROUP BY Return_Table.Customer_ID
ORDER BY TimesReturned DESC
```

Result:

```
Customer_ID TimesReturned
   Cust1         24
   Cust2         14
   Cust3         4
   Cust4         2
   .....        ....
```

Although the format for this result is correct, there has to be something wrong with my query for the values to change like this.

Answer (score 4):

Have a close look at the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust1' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust2' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust3' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust4'
```

It will match rows where:

- Date added is past month and customer id = 'cust1'
- Or customer id = 'cust2'
- Or customer id = 'cust3'

and so forth. This explains why the counts *increase* from the original (no customer id filter) counts. Add parenthesis and you should be good:

```
WHERE
 Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND
 (
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust1' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust2' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust3' OR
 Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust4'
 )
```

PS: the above is identical to the following:

```
WHERE
 Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust1' OR
 Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust2' OR
 Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust3' OR
 Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust4'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in operator instead of multiple OR:

```
SELECT TOP 20 Return_Table.Customer_ID,
COUNT(*) AS TimesReturned
 FROM Return_Table         
 WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND
 Return_Table.Customer_ID in ('cust1' ,'cust2' 'cust3','cust4')
 GROUP BY Return_Table.Customer_ID
 ORDER BY  TimesReturned DESC
```

Comment: That works but does not explain why OP's query does not work. Salman's response does an excellent job of explaining the reason.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use parentheses , when you will use multiple `or` with `and` it is better to use parenthesis otherwise according to operator precedence your result will be manupulate

```
 SELECT TOP 20 Return_Table.Customer_ID,
      COUNT(*) AS TimesReturned
     FROM Return_Table         
     WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND
     (Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust1' OR
      Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust2' OR
      Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust3' OR
      Return_Table.Customer_ID ='cust4'
       )
     GROUP BY Return_Table.Customer_ID

     ORDER BY  TimesReturned DESC
```

Comment: Should I have named the question, - 'How to use logical operators' ?

Comment: @Mrparkin you can